# Boolean recursive function always returns true

Tags: c++, recursion, boolean

I'm working on an assignment using recursion. I can't seem to figure out why my function won't return false when the number isn't in the array. For some reason, it looks to me, that the number being searched for is being added into the array. If someone can tell me where I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isMember(int[], const int, int);

int main() {

    const int SIZE = 5;
    int myArr[SIZE];
    int numSearched;

    cout << "Enter 5 numbers to be searched through." << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> myArr[i];
    }

    cout << "What number do you want to find?" << endl;
    cin >> numSearched;

    if (isMember(myArr, SIZE, numSearched)) {
        cout << "True" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "False" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool isMember(int arr[], const int S, int search) {
    bool found = false;

    cout << arr[S] << endl;

    if (arr[S] == search) {

        found = true;
        return found;
    }
    else if ((arr[S] == 0) && (arr[0] != search)) {

        return found;
    }
    else {

        return isMember(arr, S - 1, search);
    }
}
```

Comment: `else if ((arr[S] == 0) ...` should this be `else if ( (S == 0) ...`?? As of now you're looking at the value of the array, not the index.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `S` is size, `arr[S]` is out of boundary.

Comment: `arr[S]` accesses out of bounds data, as `S` is the size of the array and the last index is `S - 1`.

Comment: What's the point of the `found` variable? Why not `return true;` and `return false;`. Keep it simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people have pointed out that you have a memory access problem where you are trying to access memory outside the size of the array. Already in the top level call of the function, you cause a problem because you pass `SIZE` as the array indexing parameter. If `SIZE` is the size of your array, then `arr[SIZE-1]` is the last element of the array in memory. `arr[SIZE]` is one element beyond the end. Accessing memory that is outsize the memory footprint of your array causes undefined behavior, which is bad.

Overall, bad indexing is a huge problem here. But even if you fixed the problem above, the other problem line is here because you at trying to stop when `S` hits 0 but you wrote this incorrectly.

```
else if ((arr[S] == 0) && (arr[0] != search)) {
```

You want this to be:

```
else if (S == 0) {
```

The statement `arr[0] != search` is redundant since the conditional above it would have already checked for this. The original statement `arr[S] == 0` is trying to compare the value of `arr` at `S` to 0 rather than testing that your indexing variable is now at 0, which my suggested code does.

But this also probably explains why the function always returns true, despite the undefined behavior and that the program didn't crash. Because your function doesn't terminate appropriately, it will continually call `isMember(...,S-1,...)`. Hence, it will keep decreasing the index and changing which memory location of `arr[S]` that is accessed. This process would keep going until it either found `arr[S] == 0` or found the value you were looking for. It just happened by chance that you ran across your target value in memory somewhere before running into a 0.

Answer (score 1):

You send the index number to isMember that start from zero and when you send 5 to is member arr[5] is not definded.
And should use that method like

```
isMember(myArr, SIZE - 1, numSearched)
```

And your code don't have **End condition** I add end condition to your code to end recursion after `S < 0`

```
if (S < 0)
    return false;
```

try this ;)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isMember(int[], const int, int);

int main() {

    const int SIZE = 5;
    int myArr[SIZE];
    int numSearched;

    cout << "Enter 5 numbers to be searched through." << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> myArr[i];
    }

    cout << "What number do you want to find?" << endl;
    cin >> numSearched;

    if (isMember(myArr, SIZE - 1, numSearched)) {
        cout << "True" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "False" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool isMember(int arr[], const int S, int search) {
    if (S < 0)
        return false;
    bool found = false;

    //cout << "index is " << S << "\t" <<  arr[S] << endl;

    if (arr[S] == search) {

        found = true;
        return found;
    }

    return isMember(arr, S - 1, search); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the stop condition of the recursive function:

```
else if ((arr[S] == 0) && (arr[0] != search)) {

    return found;
}
```

You are not checking the index to be the first one, but the content to be zero. You can try something like this:

```
else if (S <= 0) {

    return false;
}
```

You also don't need to check the value to match "search", because it's redundant with the condition just before. You can also return directly false.

Comment: I would also suggest a more defensive approach, e.g. you are not checking for negative indexes.

Comment: It will be returned in the condition just before:

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was looking over something simple. I tend to overthink the problem.

Comment: Quite often the worst headaches are really simple things. The complexity is in finding out where they are :)